# Easiest way to parse command line string to subprocess list?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to figure out how to run this command using `subprocess.run()`:

```
cmd = 'find / \( -path /mnt -prune -o -path /dev -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -path /sys -prune \) -o ! -type l -type f -or -type d -printf "depth="%d/"perm="%m/"size="%s/"atime="%A@/"mtime"=%T@/"ctime"=%C@/"hardlinks"=%n/"selinux_context"=%Z/"user="%u/"group="%g/"name="%p/"type="%Y\\n'
```

I've put the command into a list, even removing items, etc:

```
cmd = [
    'find',
    '/',
    '\( -path /mnt -prune -o -path /dev -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -path /sys -prune \)',
    '-o',
    '! -type l',
    '-type f',
    '-or',
    '-type d'
]
```

I've tried running the command using `/bin/bash`:

```
cmd = '/bin/bash -c find / \( -path /mnt -prune -o -path /dev -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -path /sys -prune \) -o ! -type l -type f -or -type d -printf "depth="%d/"perm="%m/"size="%s/"atime="%A@/"mtime"=%T@/"ctime"=%C@/"hardlinks"=%n/"selinux_context"=%Z/"user="%u/"group="%g/"name="%p/"type="%Y\\n'
```

Doesn't matter. Everything I've tried does not work. Either I get no output at all, or it lists the files in my home directory, or I get an error, e.g.: `b'find: paths must precede expression: ! -type l\nUsage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]\n'`

Is there any easy way to take a command that works at the command line and just parse the string into whatever list elements `subprocess.run()` wants?

Comment: `shlex.parse()` is built for this. But using a string is a bad idea in the first place; you should be working with the native structure instead of starting with a string in the first place.

Comment: To be clear, it's `'!', '-type', '-d'` -- each word is a separate word. So the reason your original code is wrong is that you aren't splitting things out enough.

Comment: If you have a string, you can just pass it directly to `subprocess.run()` along with the `shell=True` option.

Comment: BTW, the quoting for the printf format string in your original command doesn't make any sense in bash even before starting to think about translating it to Python. What do you _want_ your output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Parsing With `shlex.split()`

After fixing the incorrect quotes in your printf string, we get:

```
cmd = r'''
find / \( -path /mnt -prune -o -path /dev -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -path /sys -prune \) -o ! -type l -type f -or -type d -printf 'depth=%d/perm=%m/size=%s/atime=%A@/mtime=%T@/ctime=%C@/hardlinks=%n/selinux_context=%Z/user=%u/group=%g/name=%p/type=%Y\\n'
'''
print(shlex.split(cmd))
```

...which emits an entirely correct result, and `subprocess.call()` works with it properly.

---

#### Building A Correct Command Line By Hand

In terms of what it looks like to do this by hand:

```
cmd = [
    'find', '/',
    '(',
             '-path', '/mnt',  '-prune',
       '-o', '-path', '/dev',  '-prune',
       '-o', '-path', '/proc', '-prune',
       '-o', '-path', '/sys',  '-prune',
    ')',
    '-o', '!', '-type', 'l',
    '-type', 'f',
    '-or',
    '-type', 'd',
    '-printf', 'depth=%d/perm=%m/size=%s/atime=%A@/mtime=%T@/ctime=%C@/hardlinks=%n/selinux_context=%Z/user=%u/group=%g/name=%p/type=%Y\n'
]
```

Note:

- Syntactic quotes change the shell's parsing mode, they don't become part of the data. `"foo"` just becomes `foo`; `"foo"bar"baz"` becomes `foobarbaz`. So you can't/shouldn't/don't try to put those quotes into the data that Python is passing in.
- This is true also for `\(`: the backslash is *shell* syntax. It doesn't actually become one of `find`'s arguments, so you leave it out.
- Any space that isn't quoted or escaped separates words; so `-type f` in shell is `'-type', 'f'`, two separate words.

Comment: I appreciate your help with the command itself! However, I'm more curious if there's a method for parsing the command from a string to the list elements that subprocess expects. I was working with shlex to do it, but still having the same issues.

Comment: Interesting! A question demonstrating the behavior of shlex here would be a good one; I'm curious to see exactly what it's missing.

Comment: @BobOdenkirk, I just revisited it, and once the shell syntax in your `-printf` string is fixed, `shlex.split()` works perfectly.